# getting the last element in list without using pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I keep getting "error: parse error on input ‘|’ " can someone tell me why? I already rewrote it to make sure all spaces where correct
here is my code:

```
 mylast :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]  
 mylast [] = []  
 mylast (x:xs)  
   | xs == [] : x  
   | otherwise = mylast xs
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. [Edit] your question to add it as text instead.

Comment: The line that matches against an empty list needs an `=` and not a `:`.  (But I'd always use a pattern match here.)

Comment: also since your method returns as list, it should return [x] , so if xs == [], then return [x].

Comment: What do you mean by "without pattern matching"? Your current code uses pattern matching!

Comment: You may do like `let last = head . reverse`.

Comment: How exactly is this not pattern matching? Your `mylast []` is pattern matching.

Answer (score 7):

The minimal change needed to fix that exact error is just to fix what is probably a typo: you wrote `xs == [] : x`, and probably meant `xs == [] = x` instead. So:

```
mylast :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
mylast [] = []
mylast (x:xs)
  | xs == [] = x
  | otherwise = mylast xs
```

This will give you a type error, because `x` is a list element, and you say `mylast` returns a list. You can fix this by making it a singleton list `[x]`, as in:

```
mylast :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
mylast [] = []
mylast (x:xs)
  | xs == [] = [x]
  | otherwise = mylast xs
```

From there, I have some stylistic comments.

1. I like your idea to return a list so that you don't need to throw an error if the input is empty. But since we're definitely returning at most one element, you might consider using `Maybe` for this role instead of `[]`; it gives a type-level guarantee of at most one element.
2. The `Eq a` constraint is unfortunate: it arises because you write `xs == []`, which doesn't actually need to call `(==)` on any elements, but nevertheless requires the user to provide an implementation of `(==)` on elements. The standard way to check if a list is empty is either to call `null` or to directly use pattern matching, neither of which require `Eq`.

Combining these two ideas, we get:

```
mylast :: [a] -> Maybe a
mylast [] = Nothing
mylast [x] = Just x -- convenient syntax sugar for mylast (x:[]) = Just x
mylast (x:xs) = mylast xs
```

This looks very idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid writing any patterns, the simplest way is probably `foldl'`:

```
mylast :: [a] -> Maybe a
mylast = foldl' (\_ x -> Just x) Nothing
```

If you prefer, you can reach down to the primitive catamorphism on lists, `foldr`:

```
mylast :: [a] -> Maybe a
mylast xs = foldr (\x r _ -> r (Just x)) id xs Nothing
```

but that's a bit trickier to understand.

`foldl'` and `foldr` are ultimately implemented using pattern matching, because that is the fundamental low-level way to inspect a list in Haskell. So there isn't any way to *really* avoid it altogether.